# Slider with caption display table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I made a slider with jQuery cycle. And I was set

```
.image img {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: table; 
}
```

And the caption

```
.caption {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;    
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

This thing align the text to middle and center. Good. But when I change slide #1  to slide #2 and after I come back at slide #1 text dosen't stay at middle.

[image]

Comment: Here is the live exemple http://html-playground.netne.net/razvy/. I have 3 images in slider. When I press > to next image and after I press < to come back at the first image the text don't stay at middle anymore

Comment: try to find another way instead of display: table-cell;  .. the problem is in that line

Comment: .image img {
 position: absolute;
} and the .caption {
 position: relative; }. When I come back to the first slider.. it's just .caption position relative is gone.

Answer (score 1):

I solve it!

The jQuery remove `display: table;` after chaning the slider. I use `display: table !important;` to fix this.